# 18.04 - Screen tearing with NVIDIA GTX 970

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I seem to be having problems with screen tearing in Ubuntu 18.04, which got confirmed by running this test:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE

I searched around in Google for a while, but all I found were recommendations to change the file `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf` and add

```
options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

But that did nothing.

These are the drivers that I am using:

[image]

What could I do to fix this?

**Update:**

This is my X Configuration:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 418.56

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL U2719D"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 90.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-2: nvidia-auto-select +1080+618, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=right}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My laptop has the same card with no tearing. Note however I'm on version 384 and have no desire for a higher version number which might complicate my setup. During system setup I did the usual trick of consulting Arch Linux's [bible](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing) that recommends:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Nvidia Card"
        Driver     "nvidia"
        VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName  "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "AllowIndirectGLXProtocol" "off"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
EndSection
```

Full Composition Pipeline and Triple Buffer are the most important.

---

Today my setup is like this:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-1-1"
    Modeline "3840x2160_54.00"  637.50  3840 4152 4568 5296  2160 2163 2168 2230 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "3840x2160_54.00"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Notice Force Composition Pipeline and Triple Buffer aren't setup here. It used to be on `nvidia-settings` GUI configuration but I don't see it there anymore.

Comment: I have no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in my filesystem...

Comment: Use `nvidia-settings` and choose the option to create the xorg configuration. Then you can tweak it from there as need be.

Comment: I have uploaded my configuration into the question. What is exactly what you think I should change?

Comment: Ok, Got it! I was applying composition pipeline, but not to ALL my monitors. Just to one of them! Thank you